# Transferring from Mysql to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to convert my old script from MYSQL to PDO, although came across a small problem. I am unable to fetch multiple results, for some reason. [Most likely my code is wrong]

Original

```
 <?php

                    $site_pages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE show_nav = '1' ORDER BY `display_nav` ASC");
                    if(mysql_num_rows($site_pages) == 0){
                        echo '';
                    }else{

                        while($n = mysql_fetch_array($site_pages)){
                            $title = $n["title"];
                            $shortname = $n["shortname"];

                            echo '<li><a href="?p='.$shortname.'" class="nav"> '.$title.' </a></li>


                    ';
                        }

                    }
                    ?>
```

My attempt:

```
    <?php

$STH - $DBH -> prepare( "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE show_nav = '1' ORDER BY `display_nav` ASC" );

$STH -> execute();
$result = $STH -> fetch();
echo $result ["title"];

?>
```

I've researched PDO fetch but unable to to get this to work.

Comment: Well, what problems are you facing after you made these changes?

Comment: did you change the `mysql_connect` & `mysql_select_db` lines also?

Comment: Yes, but ive actually fixed the problem! @Lion had the issue of it just making the page blank white..

Comment: `$STH - $DBH ->` should be `$STH = $DBH ->`

Answer (score 0):

I'd sugest you use `PDOStatement::fetchAll`.

So, you would use it this way:

```
<?php

    $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE show_nav = '1' ORDER BY `display_nav` ASC" );

    $STH -> execute();
    $result = $STH -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $result [0] ["title"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you're looking for this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE show_nav="1" ORDER BY display_nav ASC');
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```